# Where should I put .gitattributes file so that PyCharm reads it (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, git, pycharm, lf

I have a simple .gitattributes file with (only) the following in it:

```
* text eol=lf
```

in my user home directory on Windows 10. It seems that PyCharm ignores it when I pull origin/master git repository, namely the newly checked out files always have CRLF endings.

Where should I put the file in order for it to be read by PyCharm? Alternatively, is there any other way to make PyCharm always check out files with LF line endings?

Answer (score 1):

The `.gitattributes` file is parsed by git not PyCharm.

> Where should I put the file ... ?

From the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) [emphasis mine]:

> When deciding what attributes are assigned to a path, Git consults `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` file (which has the *highest precedence*), **`.gitattributes` file in the same directory as the path in question, and its parent directories up to the toplevel of the work tree** (the further the directory that contains `.gitattributes` is from the path in question, the lower its precedence). Finally global and system-wide files are considered (they have the lowest precedence).
>
> Attributes which should be **version-controlled and distributed** to other repositories (i.e., attributes of interest to all users) should go into `.gitattributes` files.

---

If you think your attributes are ignored, you can double check your current configuration with [`git-check-attr`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr), for example:

```
git check-attr eol *
git check-attr --all <some_path>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.gitattributes` file should be stored at the root of your git repository, close to the `.gitignore` or the `.gitmodules` files (if they exists), or at least close to the `.git` folder.